# Lucene Porter Stemmer not public

Tags: java, lucene, porter-stemmer

How to use the Porter Stemmber class in Lucene 3.6.2?
Here is what I have:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.PorterStemmer;
...
PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
term = stemmer.stem(term);
```

I am being told: PorterStemmer is not public in org.apache.lucene.analysis; cannot be accessed from outside package.

Edit: I also read extensively about using Snowball, but it isn't encouraged. What is the right way to stem using Lucene in Java??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) If you want to use PorterStemmer as part of Lucene token analysis process, use 
[PorterStemFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/PorterStemFilter.html)

Sample code

```
 class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
  public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    return new PorterStemFilter(new LowerCaseTokenizer(reader));
  }
 }
```

---

2) If you want to use PorterStemmer just for any other application, here is the sourcecode by author himself: [PorterStemmer in Java](http://tartarus.org/martin/PorterStemmer/java.txt)

Answer (score 0):

In Lucene later version, PorterStemmer no longer public. So

```
 class MyAnalyzer extends Analyzer {
   public final TokenStream tokenStream(String fieldName, Reader reader) {
    return new PorterStemFilter(new LowerCaseTokenizer(reader));
   }
   }
```

Or you can use SnowballAnalyzer Stemmer.[link](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/tartarus/snowball/ext/PorterStemmer.html) (SnowballAnalyzer is deprecated)

```
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer;
.
.
public static  String applyPorterStemmer(String input) throws IOException {

        PorterStemmer stemmer = new PorterStemmer();
        stemmer.setCurrent(input);
        stemmer.stem();
        return stemmer.getCurrent();
    }
```