# Lucene 4.1.0 Porter Stemmer not work properly

Tags: java, algorithm, lucene, porter-stemmer

I work with my App in Java and i use Lucene 4.1.0 to use Porter Stemmer method.
I have read and implementing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391840/stemming-english-words-with-lucene)

this is my code

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.snowball.*;
import org.tartarus.snowball.ext.PorterStemmer;


 private String stemmer(String word){
        PorterStemmer obj = new PorterStemmer();
        obj.setCurrent(word);
        obj.stem();
        return obj.getCurrent();
}
```

this method works, but Porter Stemmer did not work properly for some words e.g :

1. source >> sourc
2. coupled >> coupl
3. accompanying >> accompani

Maybe theres a bug in the algorithm?
How to solve this problem?

Comment: That's exactly how porter's algorithm works, what do you expect?

Comment: how to solve that bug? maybe there was any solution? thank you

Comment: im sorry, im dont understand porter stemmer at that time. those exactly the right output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Porter Stemmer Algorithm is expected to convert source >> sourc. Please read more about porter stemmer algorithm from [here](http://www.eecis.udel.edu/~trnka/CISC889-11S/lectures/dan-porters.pdf)

Comment: thank you for the answer, anything to do to solve the problem?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with stemming?

Comment: There will always be some cases in with there is over-stemming. Maybe what you are trying achieve is Lemmatisation. **The main purpose of stemming is to map different forms of a word to a single form** and that is what porter algorithm does. So it is **NOT a bug**. But lemmatisation is more complex to achieve.

Comment: i use WordNet in my app, and i want to set a keyword from text as the input for WordNet. so, i need a single form from a word

Answer (score 0):

You can use a word suggester on top of porter stemmer. For word suggestion you can use "suggester basic in java"