# how to do fuzzy search in Lucene.net in asp.net?

Tags: c#, lucene.net

we have creating lucene.net index and search based on this URL http://sonyblogpost.blogspot.in/. but we want the output like follow.

example: if i search "featured"
 i want to show related terms like "featured","featuring","feature".

Anyone can help me.
thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To perform a Fuzzy search you'll create a `MultiFieldQueryParser` Below is an example on how to do this:

```
var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, new[] { "field1", "field2" }, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
```

Your version of Lucene.Net may vary.

Next you will get a Fuzzy query from the parser like this:

```
var query = parser.GetFuzzyQuery("fieldName", "featured", 0.7f);
```

The float value of `0.7f` is the minimum similarity. You can tweak this number until you get the desired results. The number cannot be more than `1.0f`. Executing this query using an Lucene Searcher will give you the results you expect.

Comment: i have already added the MultiFueldQueryParser... but where should i add the "var query = parser.GetFuzzyQuery("fieldName", "featured", 0.7f);". the followings are the my search and query.....
  public BooleanQuery QueryMaker(string searchString, string[] searchfields)
        {
            var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, searchfields, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
            var finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            string searchText;
            searchText = searchString.Replace("+", "");

Comment: After you have created the MultiFieldQueryParser. You will then add the query to your finalQuery like this finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

Comment: hi i added these. but not occur any fuzzy search.. my code is below. var parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, searchfields, new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29));
            var finalQuery = new BooleanQuery();
            var query = parser.GetFuzzyQuery("ContentText", searchString, 0.7f);  // ContentText is column name. searchString is input string.
            finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

Comment: this is my final answer. 
Query query = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("ContentText", searchString));
            finalQuery.Add(query, BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for stemming: [Stemming English words with Lucene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391840/stemming-english-words-with-lucene) - The link is Java, but you should be able to identify the corresponding parts of the lucene .Net API.