# Lucene.Net for full-text search on the site

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, lucene, full-text-search, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.Net for full-text search on the site, in general it turned out to achieve good results, but there is one problem that I can not solve in any way

For example, in the database there is a product with the name
**Sony Alpha a7 III Mirrorless Digital Camera**

The task is to find this product by different queries.
The user can search for it in different ways.
For example, right now the results are as follows:

```
Sony a7 - in this case everything works perfectly.
a7 - already a little bit worse
7a sony - bad
a 7 - very bad.
```

maybe there is some method how can I get better results from Lucene?
thank you in advance

I made a separate field where all these variants are specified, but for a database where tens of thousands of goods are stored, it is a problem to do it manually.

Comment: Are you doing a [fuzzy search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18851208/how-to-do-fuzzy-search-in-lucene-net-in-asp-net)?

Comment: I Use fuzzy search too, but apparently he's not very good at it. thanks