# Stemming text in java

Tags: java, lucene, stemming

im searching for a possibility to stemm strings in java.
First I wanted to do it with lucene but all the examples
I found in the web were deprecated. (SnowballAnalyzer, 
PorterStemmer, ...)
I just want to stemm whole sentences.

```
public static String stemSentence(String sentence) {
    ...
    return stemmedSentence;
}
```

How can i do it?

Comment: This link have some solutions for you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5391840/stemming-english-words-with-lucene

Comment: Lucene's stemming analyzers are all language specific, housed in the [org.apache.lucene.analysis](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/) package.  Pick your language and away you go. (also, while `SnowballAnalyzer` is certainly deprecated, `PorterStemmer` is not.  It's used by `EnglishAnalyzer`, after all)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make this:

```
public static String stem(String string) throws IOException {
    TokenStream tokenizer = new StandardTokenizer(Version.LUCENE_47, new StringReader(string));
    tokenizer = new StandardFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenizer);
    tokenizer = new LowerCaseFilter(Version.LUCENE_47, tokenizer);
    tokenizer = new PorterStemFilter(tokenizer);

    CharTermAttribute token = tokenizer.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class);

    tokenizer.reset();

    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    while(tokenizer.incrementToken()) {
        if(stringBuilder.length() > 0 ) {
            stringBuilder.append(" ");
        }

        stringBuilder.append(token.toString());
    }

    tokenizer.end();
    tokenizer.close();

    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```