# Stemming english words using Lucene 6.5.1

Tags: java, text-mining, stemming, zend-lucene

I want to stemming tokens in a text with Lucene 6.5.1
I've seen many example about this, but all of them used old version of Lucene.
the Apache's website introduce TokenFilter class for stemming but i cant use that.

Comment: Why can't you use that? What did you try so far and where exactly did you fail?

Comment: There's a previous question that covers this exactly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43621672/stemming-english-words-using-lucene-6

Comment: This question is exactly my problem, but the answer introduce PorterStemFilter class and i dont find it in lucene libraries!